# Google Plus login not work on ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus-signin

I would like to use Google Plus api in my ios 7 app, but its not work.
I write into the appdelegate.m file this:

```
static NSString *const kClientId = @"XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientId;}
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation {
return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];}
```

In my viewcontroller i wrote this:

```
- (void) loginWithGooglePlus{
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
[signIn setScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject: @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]];
//signIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusUserinfoEmail];
[signIn setDelegate:self];
//signIn.delegate = self;

NSLog(@"started g+ login");
[signIn authentication];
//[signIn trySilentAuthentication];
[self reportAuthStatus];}
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Status: Authentication error: %@", error);
    return;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Success!");
}
//[self reportAuthStatus];}
- (void)reportAuthStatus {
if ([GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication) {
    NSLog(@"Status: Authenticated");
} else {
    // To authenticate, use Google+ sign-in button.
    NSLog(@"Status: Not authenticated");
}}
```

And my problem is that the finishedWithAuth callback method never run. I dont know whats wrong.

Comment: you are using only g+ integration or more like fb?

Comment: had you set `GPPSignIndelegate`

Comment: I use fb, twitter and would like g+ too, and yes i set GPPSignIndelegate

Comment: with fb and g+, you code in appdelegate `openurl` method?

Comment: show ur code  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication -- souse code

Answer (score 1):

I dont have enough reputation to comment.But i would like to say that my app was rejected from appstore last time saying Google+ oAuth login is going out of app for authentication.You can search and see that this is a common issue.

This was the message i got from appstore :***"We found the following issues with the user interface of your app: The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for creating an account or logging in, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able to create an account or log in without opening Safari first."***

Google+ login will open safari for login,which is not supported by apple.I removed the google+ login and then my my app was accepted by appstore.

Do a research about this issue.Best of luck,dont waste time.

see [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/37) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900)..you can find more in stackoverflow

Comment: you are welcome.:)..I tried alternative ways to do the authentication within the app.But i could not do that.So i removed the G+ login.You can try to do it within the app(webView or something)..only if u have time.And if u could do it,please tell me too.

Comment: My problem was that i write this:[signIn authentication]; but i need this: [signIn authenticate];

Comment: Thats ok.But are u still going to use the G+ login?

Comment: Seriously,do a research about that.I took almost 15-20 days for the review process and the app was rejected.Then i made some changes and it took another 15 days for the next review process.

Comment: @abhi Google has provided new SDK which solves the problem of app rejection. here is the link of new dev site [  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start  ]

Comment: @Learner,the link you have provided  here is google login.google plus login can be the following one https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

Comment: @abhi I used the sdk and I can retrive the google plus user profile pic etc